# How can I add Images from my postgreSQL database in Next.js?

Tags: typescript, postgresql, next.js, vercel

I'm building a web app in Next.js. The mainpage is containing a Card component with an  tag that's supposed to show a movie poster. I'm trying to add the poster from an object in my postgreSQL database (a url). My question is how I get ahold of that url and use it in my  tag.

I know how the url from the database:

actions.ts

```
'use server'
import { sql } from "@vercel/postgres"

const allPosters = await sql`
SELECT poster FROM hardcoded_movies`
allPosters.rows[i].poster // here I get the URL
```

Now I need to import this to my Card component and use it as the src in my  tag.
I've tried putting it in a function but I'm not quite getting the hang of it.

How should I do this?